# Can't find clear examples to understand smoothing in hidden markov models

Tags: artificial-intelligence, hidden-markov-models, markov-chains, bayesian-networks

I am currently trying to learn hidden markov models in the course Artificial Intelligence. However I couldn't find any example about smoothing to understand it clearly.

I have understood in which situations we use smoothing, but I could not understand how to implement that.

Can anyone help about that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the current observation (of the hidden state) to update the beliefs of past hidden states.

There's perhaps a clearer explanation over at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281877/598682.

I also found Pedro Domingos' book The Master Algorithm gives a great conceptual understanding, including how the HMM relates to a Kalman filter:

"If the states and observations are continuous variables instead of discrete ones, the HMM becomes what’s known as a Kalman filter. Economists use Kalman flters to remove noise from time series of quantities like GDP, inflation, and unemployment. The “true” GDP values are the hidden states; at each time step, the true value should be similar to the observed one, but also to the previous true value, since the economy seldom makes abrupt jumps. The Kalman filter trades off these two, yielding a smoother curve that still accords with the observations."

"CHAPTER SIX In the Church of the Reverend Bayes.” The Master Algorithm: How the Quest for the Ultimate Learning Machine Will Remake Our World, by Pedro Domingos, Basic Books, a Member of the Perseus Books Group, 2018, p. 155.